# Android - Issue with Gridview inside Scrollview

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am using the [ExpandableHeightGridView](https://gist.github.com/jiahuang/2591977)

Its used in my app to load images. its working fine but if I load images more than about 35 to 40 images then it gives blank screen also hides other controls in my scroll view.
Can anybody help me to fix this.

**Edit**

Code:

```
package com.abc.util;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class ExpandableHeightGridView extends GridView
{

boolean expanded = false;

public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public boolean isExpanded()
{
    return expanded;
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
    if (isExpanded())
    {
        // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
        // View.MEASURED_SIZE_MASK represents the largest height possible.
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    else
    {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}

public void setExpanded(boolean expanded)
{
    this.expanded = expanded;
}
}
```

XML:

```
<com.abc.util.ExpandableHeightGridView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/gridViewImages"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:verticalSpacing="10dp"/>
```

Adapter:

```
public class GridViewImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private ArrayList<String> list;
    private ActivitiesDetail activityImages;

    public GridViewImageAdapter(ArrayList<String> list, ActivitiesDetail activityImages)
    {
        this.list = list;
        this.activityImages = activityImages;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_item_grid_view_images, null);
        try
        {
            final TextView textViewCaption = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblGridViewCellValue);
            fonts.setFontOpenSansRegular(textViewCaption);
            final String[] imageDetail = list.get(position).split("~");
            textViewCaption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    if (dialogs == null)
                    {
                        dialogs = new Dialogs(ActivitiesDetail.this);
                    }
                    dialogs.showImageCaptionDialog(imageDetail[0], textViewCaption, activityImages);
                }
            });
            textViewCaption.setText(imageDetail[1]);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewGridCellImage);
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    if (imagesSelected)
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivitiesDetail.this, ImageSlider.class);
                        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("KEY_ARRAY_IMAGES", list);
                        intent.putExtra("KEY_POSITION", position);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out);
                    }
                }
            });
            convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPlayOverlay).setVisibility(View.GONE);

            Picasso.with(ActivitiesDetail.this).load("file://" + imageDetail[0]).resize(100, 100).into(imageView);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    public void setList(ArrayList<String> list)
    {
        this.list = list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void clear()
    {
        list.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post code?

Comment: never use gridview inside scrollview. gridview scrolls by itself and has it own scrolling mechanism

Comment: please avoid to use Scroll in GridView , listview , expandable list view etc. Remove ScrollView tag from XML.

Comment: @Haresh I have posted code as well.

Comment: @M.NasserJavaid...3 month before i am getting same kind of issue and it was issue of object locking and unlocking . I am not sure but may be same thing is happening here... When you load 30-35 image your view get finish but still object are blocked. MAY be ....Its only a suggestion.......

Answer (score 2):

Generally you shouldn't use a scrollable view inside ScrollView but if your requirement is so then you have to manually in the code by changing the LayoutParams of GridView.

This is how we change LayoutParams:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) gridView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = rowHeight*(imageList.size()/noOfColumns);
mUploadImageList.setLayoutParams(params);
```

where gridView is your GridView, rowHeight is the height of one row, imageList is a list of images we are showing in GridView, noOfColumns is the number of columns in our GridView. You can set the rowHeight and noOfColumns in res/values for easy accessible.

Answer (score 1):

**Try to replace your adapter with this**

```
public class GridViewImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private ArrayList<String> list;
        private ActivitiesDetail activityImages;
        private Context context;

        public GridViewImageAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> list, ActivitiesDetail activityImages)
        {
            this.context=context;
            this.list = list;
            this.activityImages = activityImages;
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

            ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView==null){
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_item_grid_view_images, null,false);
                holder.textViewCaption = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblGridViewCellValue);
                holder.imageViewGridCellImage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewGridCellImage);
                holder.imageViewPlayOverlay = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPlayOverlay);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            fonts.setFontOpenSansRegular(holder.textViewCaption);
            final String[] imageDetail = list.get(position).split("~");
            holder.textViewCaption.setText(imageDetail[1]);
            holder.textViewCaption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    if (dialogs == null)
                    {
                        dialogs = new Dialogs(ActivitiesDetail.this);
                    }
                    dialogs.showImageCaptionDialog(imageDetail[0], v, activityImages);
                }
            });


            holder.imageViewGridCellImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (imagesSelected) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivitiesDetail.this, ImageSlider.class);
                        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("KEY_ARRAY_IMAGES", list);
                        intent.putExtra("KEY_POSITION", position);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.left_out);
                    }
                }
            });
            holder.imageViewPlayOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            Picasso.with(ActivitiesDetail.this).load("file://" + imageDetail[0]).resize(100, 100).into(holder.imageViewGridCellImage);


            return convertView;
        }

        private class ViewHolder{
            TextView textViewCaption;
            ImageView imageViewGridCellImage;
            ImageView imageViewPlayOverlay;
        }

        public void setList(ArrayList<String> list)
        {
            this.list = list;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        private void clear()
        {
            list.clear();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have added images using LinearLayout inside scrollview and it again showing blank in case of more than 35 or 40 images, and I think, Its problem with scrollview not with gridview.

Comment: i just try to correct your adapter code and try to remove scroll check what happens ?

Comment: Its working without scrollview in both cases, 1st with Gridview and secondly also working with items in LineraLayout. But in my situation I have to use Gridview or LinerLayout inside the Scrollview.